# How to change background and/or border of the submenu box?

Tags: css, wordpress

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnTzc.jpg)

I'm making a website on my test site: http://work.jivova.com
and now I'm stucked with searching a way to change the submenu box background colour (shown in the screenshot) to semitransparent and also to have an option to remove the box border using the custom CSS.

I have tried several solutions, none of them worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Martin, can you make a small example showing your issue? Questions linking to an external website are considered off-topic, your code must be presented here. You can [edit] the question and use Stack Snippets (just like jsfiddle) to show the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  Also, please read: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I put there a screenshot, showing what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a style in your main stylesheet, `.main-navigation ul ul` that is giving your submenu that border. If you only want the `sub-menu` class items to have no border, create a new style (which should come after the rule above in the cascade -- it looks like you're using WordPress, so this should go in a child theme):

```
.main-navigation ul ul.sub-menu {
    border : 0px; 
}
```

If you want *all* instances of a ul inside a ul inside your main-navigation, you can leave off the `.sub-menu` part.

As for the background color, I'm not really clear on what you want to do -- a background for the whole box, or change the grey background you get on the hover state? If you mean the grey background that's being added by the style `.main-navigation li li:hover, .main-navigation li li.focus`. You can use the [documentation on opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) to change the transparency of that background grey to something else, and add that new rule to your child theme, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Next time better add the code of your menu in here, so it also helps someone if your site get changed.

Here is the custom CSS which will make the menu transparent and removes the border:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); /* 0.75 - WHITE */
  border: 0;
}
```

If you wanna change the color or the transparent effect also on the hover you need:

```
.main-navigation li li:hover, .main-navigation li li.focus {
   background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);  /* 0.75 - RED */
}
```

If you want to make the whole submenu transparent, not only the background you have to add:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
  opacity: .75; /* This is also working for hover or active states */
}
```

Comment: If you like the answer please accept  it or upvote it in the left site. This is how Stackoverflow works. If you have more Questions, feel free to ask.

Just watched your site, you used `border: 0px` its enough to use `border: 0` (both are working fine, but without px you save 2 chars to load)